# May a meat restaurant make siyumim during the Nine Days?

Tags: meat, nine-days

4 rabbis in my neighborhood have stated that one should not intentionally plan a *siyum* during the Nine Days for the sole purpose of wanting to eat meat.

I think I have also seen this attitude mentioned as by the OU on their halacha pages and pamphlets. (I.e., while one can assume that they would apply this attitude to their supervised places, the pamphlet I saw this in was a general OU halacha pamphlet, not a kosher OU establishment pamphlet.)

There is a Chinese meat restaurant in my neighborhood that has siyumim throughout the day. Approximately each 20 minutes, a siyum is given in some section of the restaurant so that customers may eat meat.

The restaurant doesn't want to serve parve. They tried this one year, and they lost money by staying open. It cost them more money between materials, salary, electricity, etc. than they recovered by their customer volume during that week.

Is an exception to the siyum policy made for a meat restaurant so that it may stay in business during the week?

The restaurant is supervised by the local Va'ad, and I'm asking this question independent of a Va'ad or supervising org's official policy. For this question, assume that no one stated an explicit restriction as part of their kashrut criteria.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this restaurant would otherwise abide by this policy? Is it OU supervised for instance?

Comment: @DoubleAA See edits. Assume that there is no supervisory policy regarding this rule.

Comment: I should add that the fact that no local rabbi did not object, doesn't mean that they give permission and allow this, either. They're just not reacting and not objecting for whatever reason.

Comment: The people taking part in the siyum should have been only those actually learning for the siyum. Other customers who just want to eat meat should not be involved at all.

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't think that's a requirement for any siyum at any time throughout the year. Certainly, in camp, we didn't have 500 boys and girls completing the same *masechta*.

Comment: @DanF This was said at a shiur about the nine days specifically. I don't know about camp, but it was said about a restaurant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Aruch HaShulchan [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.551.28?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes negatively about intentionally planning a siyum during the Nine Days for the sole purpose of eating meat.

A siyum in a hotel/restaurant is discussed in Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky's Kovetz Halachos [below]. He finds it halachically difficult to explain this practice, however once people do this, one should not object.

[image: here]

Comment: Thanks. The camp is a good analogy. That explains the rabbis being quiet about it. Personally, I would be more lenient about the restaurant as it loses business otherwise. Not every place can make it serving pareve during the week, esp. if they charge the same prices.

Comment: @DanF - He mentions hotels as well, so it's his analogy. Also, he differentiates between boys camps and girls camps.